# Is it bad to have your test and production environments on the same machine?

Tags: language-agnostic, development-environment

Would it be bad to have things set up so that `MySite.com` is production and `test.MySite.com` is test?  Both running off the same machine.  The site doesn't get a lot of traffic.

**UPDATE**

I am talking about an ASP.NET web application running on a Windows server.

Comment: Question for the dev team behind Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Of a company in this situation, my friend Max once said, "The problem wasn't that they didn't have a test system - what the didn't have was a *production* system!"

Comment: +1 I'm going to steal that quote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is a bad idea.

Suppose your test code has a bug that consumes all memory/cpu/disk space? Then your production site goes down.

Have separate machines for production and test and use DNS to point the URLs to each.

---

Edit (more points):

If the sites share a machine, they share an IP address, so when using an IP address to access a site, you will not know whether you are on production or test.

When sharing the same machine, deployment can be tricky, you have to be extra careful not to deploy untested code to production (easier to do, since both live on the same machine).

The security considerations for production and test should be separate - this kind of setup makes it more difficult.

Comment: Good point.  Do you have any more? I'm trying to prepare a list of potential pitfalls for my boss.

Comment: Hey what if only concern is resources, then using container images and having hard resource limits isn't a good idea?

Comment: You could treat container images with hard limits as "separate machines", assuming they can really be isolated from each other in this way in the host (not always possible - look up noise neighbour). We didn't have this kind of tech when this answer was written, back in 2010, @AkhilSurapuram

Answer (score 5):

It'd be really hard to test whether environment updates (new version of php/perl/python/apache/kernel/whatever) with test and production on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea. When you have a new untested feature it may kill the production site.

Answer (score 1):

Is compliance with any kind of standard an issue?  Generally you want developers to have lots of access to test environments so they can resolve issues.  However, it's not always a good idea (or even allowed) for developers to have the same level of access to production systems.

Comment: Not at the moment but that's something I'm trying to change.  Right now it's a free for all.  Dev box directly to production.  What kind of standards are there out there for us to comply with?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: There are all kinds of little-known standards for different industries, as well as a few big ones.  For example, if you ever take credit card information then PCI compliance becomes very important.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes. When developing, there are a lot of things that could go awry, like @Oded mentioned. By having a dedicated webserver run your main site, you avoid the complexity of having duplicated databases, virtual hosts, etc. You could certainly make `test.mysite.com` publicly available, though.

As a customer, often times, the first thing I do is visit a company's website. If the site is inaccessible, even briefly, it looks unprofessional and I quickly lose interest. You do not want to lose business because you were too cheap to buy one extra computer!

**Edit:** I see from your comments above that this is indeed a business server. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

*"Good, bad, I'm the guy with the gun."* - Ash

Bad is really a range.  It can be anywhere between replacing motherboards with the power plugged in and wet hands, to using excessively short variable names.  What you really want to know is what are the tradeoffs.  You obviously know some of the benefits or you wouldn't be thinking about using the production server for testing.

The big con is the test code is running in a **shared** environment with production.  If there is no sandbox (process limits, memory limits, disk limits, chroot file system, etc) you risk impacting the production server is something goes awry in the testing.  You may accidentally DOS your self by consuming all of a particular resource.  You may accidentally remove the production site.  Someone may think it's okay to do a load test.  If you are fine with taking those risks, then you can go ahead an run your test app on the production server.

BTW: It is bad.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is not platform specific, I'll try to answer in a general form. I'll lso refer only to the "same machine" part of your question, since the "domain name" should be very easy to  change ... if all common precautions have been taken.

What you really need is to isolate environments. Depending on the technology used, that may mean "separate machines" or not.

As an example, a lot small to medium banks in the world run their critical systems on one mainframe. It's not unusual for one of those beasts to cost (peripherals and all) six figures.  Some of them opted to have separate, smaller machines for development and testing, while others run hundreds of environments (sometimes as VMs) on the same machine. The tricky detail is that the mainframe hardware and OS do provide real and consistent isolation between those environments, assigning disks, CPUs, comm channels, credentials, libraries, OS modules, DBs, etc, etc based on a strict policy that can be as granular as you want.

The problem with many other platforms is that finding the way to isolate the environments is up to you, while in a dinosaur platform is provided by the grace of HAL.

HTH!