# Is it bad to have your test and production environments on the same machine? - running container Images

Tags: testing, production-environment, infrastructure

I know there is a question exits on this topic [Is it bad to have your test and production environments on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441410/is-it-bad-to-have-your-test-and-production-environments-on-the-same-machine)

There the major concern's that's discussed is production site can get down due resource issue. if your buggy code occupies entire server resources.

If resources is the only concern then **How about using containers and having hard resource limits to the containers**